# Reading Firebase data returns null Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
public void RetreiveNewQuestions(){
    Random random = new Random();
    int questionInt1;
    questionInt1 = random.nextInt(2-1) + 1;
    String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("questions").child("animal").child("1").child("question").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           String question1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
           question[0] = question1;

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

This method is supposed to read questions randomly, but first for testing purposes I tried to see if it can read one question, but did not work.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    questionRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("questions");
    category = "animal";
    RetreiveNewQuestions();

    String quizData[][] = {
            //Format, {Question, right answer, option1, option2, option3}
            {question[0], "Log", "Tree", "Knee"," Bee"},
            { "Potato", "Rar", "Laugh", "Test","Minute"}
    };
```

[What my data looks like in Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uf91q.png)

Comment: Can you explain more "but did not work."

Comment: Try going till child("1") and then under onDataChange method use ddataSnapshot to get the data.

Comment: String.class in dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class); is not required

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only the first question, then please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("questions").child("animal").child("1");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String question = dataSnapshot.child("questions").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", question);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

If you want to get all the questions, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference animalRef = rootRef.child("question").child("animal");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String question = ds.child("question").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", question);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
animalRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```